# How to get (almost) identical values of a multidimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a little problem with my data: I have two sets of x and y data points in a multidimensional array and I want to find the x, y pair which is the same for both sets. Problem is, they are not exactly the same but only +- epsilon.

```
a = [[1.62947485e+03 1.62947086e+03 1.62946687e+03 1.62946289e+03
1.62945890e+03 1.62945491e+03 1.62945092e+03 1.62944693e+03
1.62944294e+03 1.62943896e+03]
[0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 2.00000000e+00 3.00000000e+00
 4.00000000e+00 5.00000000e+00 6.00000000e+00 7.00000000e+00
 8.00000000e+00 9.00000000e+00]] 

b = [[0. 1.62945092e+03 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9. 10.]
 [441.32825424 6.0000001e+00 441.33627623 441.34028723 441.34429822
 441.34830922 441.35232022 441.35633121 441.36034221 441.36435321]]
```

So in this case I want to find [1.62945092e+03, 6.00000000e+00]

I would want to avoid looping through the whole thing because I have to do it for 2,2052 dimensional arrays quite a lot of times and this would simply take too long.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with '2,2052 dimensional'? Do you simple mean that you have a list of 22052 lists?

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understanding what you mean with 'x, y pair which is the same for both sets'. In your example 1.6e3 and 6.0 are split over two dimensions in a and in the same list in b.

Comment: Perhaps the `unittest.Testcase.assertAlmostEqual` function would be of interest